# Send generated audio to UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, audio, uilocalnotification, mainbundle

I have an alarm app that plays .mp3 alarms and uses one .wav for local notifications.

As an update I just spent laying down a massive amount of code setting up and upgrade system that convers the allocated MP3s into Wavs,, so the user will hear any of the chosen alarms even in local notifs.

Now that I finished EVERYTHING it turns out I need to pull local notif .wavs from the main bundle, but you cant write to the main bundle.

Joke's on me....

From what I've found this is a lost cause but maybe some has a work around. Or does anione thing its worth making contact with apple?

P.S. Upgrade system is a nice pice of work, background multi treated, robust for future upgrades, takes 8 seconds to convert 24 mp3s on iphone 4.... So sad....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot play app-generated audio in UILocalNotifications (exception: jailbroken devices) because writing to the main bundle is not permitted as you already stated. You should have known that before starting the project.

Comment: Right you are phix that a bit more research would have been key. This is just one more feature for an upgrade so its not a major problem. I have found with iOS that a lot of times there are workarounds that can be done in situations where no at first there is none apparent and that apple will accept if it adds to your product. Thanks for posting.